# Xcode 5 & Cocos2d: Random Errors Like: 'No Known Class Method for Selector 'scene'?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors, automatic-ref-counting

I'm really confused by the random errors that come up in Obj-c?
The below is an error that came up after making minor unrelated changes in another class.
Furthermore, the error remains even through I've undone the new bool i added to the header of a completely separate class!

can some one please help me here, because my program i've been working on for a while now won't build at all, and I'm totally lost since I've no idea with the compiler is ignoring the above declared CCScene 'scene'...

Thanks for your help

```
@implementation mainMenu

+(CCScene *)scene
{
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
mainMenu *layer = [mainMenu node];
[scene addChild: layer];
return scene;
}

- (void)loadAgainstTheClockMode:(id)sender
{
// Reload the current scene
CCScene *scene = [HelloWorldLayer scene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionZoomFlipX     transitionWithDuration:0.2 scene:scene]];
```

Screen Shot...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfrVB.png

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call the `scene` method on the `HelloWorldLayer` class.  You're pointing at the `+(CCScene *)scene` method in the current class, but that's not the `HelloWorldLayer` class.  It's in a class implementation for a class clearly labeled `mainMenu` (which should be capitalized).

If you intend to call the method in the code provided, you need to change your code from:

```
CCScene *scene = [HelloWorldLayer scene];
```

To:

```
CCScene *scene = [mainMenu scene];
```

OR

```
CCScene *scene = [[self class] scene];
```

OR

Create a `scene` method in the `HelloWorldLayer` class and put it's declaration in its `.h` file.

Comment: Yes you are correct! - Unfortunately I messed up a little. The code in my post is correct after all. I realise now that the scene from the HelloWorldLayer class was for some reason missing from its .h file... Replasing it has fixed the problem. I've no idea why it was missing. Also, why must the mainMenu be capitalised? thanks again

Comment: Because it's a class and in Objective-C, we capitalize classes and lower case methods and variables.